# How to split values in different column in different lines in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to split the values of the column in different lines

Currently , the values are in one single line as shown below, i am trying to separate it in 3 different lines
[image]

I have tried the below code snippet but didn't work.

```
 const listEmails = [
    'a@a.com',
    'b@b.com',
    'c@c.com',
    'd@d.com',
    'e@e.com',
    'f@f.com',
    'g@g.com',
    'h@h.com',
    'i@i.com',
  ];
  const listItems = listEmails.map(email => (
    <CheckBoxContainer>
      <CheckboxWithLabel
        onChange={() => props.dispatch(updateSelectionEmail(email))}
        checked={props.isChecked.includes(email)}
      >
        <StyledCheckboxLabel>{email}</StyledCheckboxLabel>
      </CheckboxWithLabel>
    </CheckBoxContainer>
  ));

const CheckBoxContainer = styled.div`
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 18px;
  div[class*='with-label__CheckBoxText'] {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
```

Expected Output should be below:
[image]

Comment: There are a lot fo ways to do this. The easiest would be to look into using Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using styled-components, try placing your `listItems` in a styled container which has `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column`.

Like this:

```
const StyledCheckBoxList = styled.div`
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
`

<StyledCheckBoxList>
 {listItems}
</StyledCheckBoxList>
```

You can also add a fixed hight and use flex-wrap if you want the items to break into a new column once they reach the bottom of your container (like in the screenshot you provided).

**Update**

I've created a [simplified version of your example](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68213697-un1x6), notice how I'm using a fixed height and a `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container in order to make the list move to a new column once it reaches the fixed height.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this solution already, <Container>{listItems}</Container> , But This comes all values in a row. I am trying to split 2 or 3 in one column then the other values in another line as shown in the screen shot

Comment: Can you please add the code to <Container/> and <CheckBoxContainer /> components to your question?

Comment: I have added it to my question

Comment: Strange, your code looks fine. I've updated my answer and added a sandbox with a simplified example of what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you can compare it to your code to figure out what you are missing.